# NetBeans 8.2 configure code assitance to C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans8.2 for C++ project and would like to use C++11 features. My problem is that somehow the code assistance of NetBeans doesn't manage to resolve shared_ptr symbol and hence reds it as error although the compilation successfully passes.
I've googled about it a lot - and seen all the options of set __cplusplus macro to 201103L -  but it doesn't help to me. Netbeans ignores it and I still have this annoying message of "unable to resolve symbol".
I've also set the C++ Standard to C++11 in tools->properties->code assistance->c++ compiler.

Does anybody have any idea for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since compilation is successful your compiler settings seem ok.

What you can do:

- **`Context menu of Project -> Code Assistance`**

  - **`Reparse Project`**
  - Since NB8.2 available: **`Clean C/C++ cache and restart IDE`**
- ***Clean*** (aka. delete) ***cache manually*** and restart IDE (you see the cache directory used at Help -> About – on Linux it's usually `~/.cache/netbeans/<NB version>`
- Check ***IDE Log*** for error (View -> IDE Log). You can also clean the log, reparse the project and see only the errors of that parse.
- Create a new C++ project with C++11 enabled an test if you have the same issue there.